# Empty vector in large array of objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a large array of objects (10s Millions) of class A and I want to add a vector as a member to the class A. This vector is needed just for few percent of objects in the array. I was wondering, would it be a wise choice to add a vector to the class? how much memory will take an empty vector?

Comment: `sizeof(vector)`....

Comment: Isn't it always same before reserve or resize?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does the large array contain instances of `A`, or should it be made part of class `A`? If so, what kind of objects does the vector contain?

Comment: the large array contain instances of A

Comment: And you want to make it part of `A`? So each instance of `A` would contain a lot of other instances of `A`?

Comment: No the array is completely seperate, I just wonder if adding an element of empty vector to all instances will cause memory waste

Comment: OK, now I understand. It will cause some overhead, yes. How much overhead? @Pubby wrote that...

Comment: If you don't want to pay for that memory overhead, you might consider using a separate `unordered_map<A, vector>` to associate instances of `A` to their corresponding vectors. But then you have to manually keep your large array and this helper map consistent (e.g. remove entries from the map when the corresponding objects are removed from the array or cease to exist, etc.)

Comment: Typical vector implementations take up three words, so for 10 million objects, that's between 100 and 300 MB memory. Not a big deal on modern systems...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know

Comment: ``sizeof(vector<T>)`` is always the same. You want to check whether that is a significant overhead compared to ``sizeof(A)`` for a vector-less ``A``.

Comment: Andy's suggestion is good.  Depending on whether/how/when you insert/delete/reorder/change elements, you might prefer to use the vector index itself as a key in your additional container, and/or use a sorted vector of `std::pair<size_t|A, vector<int>>` that you can binary search rather than an `unordered_map` - lots of tuning options.

Comment: Another idea, if you never need to *resize* the vectors: Have a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. That one only takes up one word (one pointer), and you can *optionally* initialize or assign it a `new T[N]`.

Comment: how big is class A?  how much memory is on a typical system running this software?  what kind of operations do you usually do to the set of A?

Answer (score 1):

Now we know that empty vector are not very “big” (VC2012x64 intellisense show `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is 16 byte). If `sizeof(A)` is much bigger than size-of vector adding a vector member to A could be a good solution for you. But if it is not good, and will add to much memory, and really not many A has the vector, I’d create a second container with the vectors. For example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
unordered_map<size_t , vector<T>> VectorForA;
```

where size_t is mean to be the type of the index of the big array of A, and `vector<T>` the type of the vector you want to add to A. This could be good for a fixed index "big" array. If somehow the A's in the big array dont have fixed positions, making the value of A the key could led to a simpler code(also, only if the values of A dont repeat).

NOTE: I was (I'm) wating to see a full answer from  @Andy Prowl or @Tony D with I think will be very usefull